# Cannot validate File required in Vuetify 2.0.5

Tags: validation, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I can validate File size but cannot validate required in Vuetify 2.0.5 using  with rules.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The file input takes an array of values, so the rules should be like this,

```
fileRules: [
   v => !!v || 'File is required',
   v => (v && v.length > 0) || 'File is required',
]
```

And form should be

```
<v-form ref='fileForm'>
   <v-file-input label="File Input" :rules="fileRules"></v-file-input>
   <v-layout justify-center>
      <v-btn @click="uploadFile">Upload</v-btn>
   </v-layout>
</v-form>
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/subashdbc/pen/eYpVOKq)

Comment: this is not working for me, can you please provide a working snippet?

Comment: @yukashimahuksay Added a codepen which might help you

Comment: your codepen is using multiple, but your code is not. I don't want multiple files.

Comment: Replace with this condition on rules, rules: [
      v => !!v || 'File is required'
    ]